# Creating control events in the Visual Studio IDE when programming in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have been developing VB.Net winform apps using Visual Studio for several years and I am now just trying to get my head around C#. When I am using Visual Studio (currently VS 2017) to develop VB.Net winform apps I have three dropdowns at the top of the IDE that allows me to select the project, control and then events for the selected control.  So if I want to handle, for example, the MouseDown event of a TextBox I simply select the MouseDown event in the dropdown and Visual Studio creates the event handler for me.

In C#, if I double click the control in the Design view it will automatically create the event handler for the default event, but what about all of the other events?  Is there a C# equivalent way to VB.Net to generate the handler automatically or do I always have to create the event handlers manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch to the event tab on your control property page and double-click your event and VS creates exact THIS handler for you.

[image: visualisation]